# How to to grouping and sorting at the same time for a list box in xaml?

Tags: sorting, xaml, listbox, uwp, grouping

I want to do sorting and grouping at the same time for my listbox itemssource.
I need something like this [Grouping and Sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dkvM.png)

I am trying this for now:

`<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" x:Name="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True">
 </CollectionViewSource>`

and

```
<ListBox Background="#282828" x:Name="sendersearchresults" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
                            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                                <TextBlock Foreground="#FFCF06" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding FirstName,Converter={StaticResource PrefixValueConverter},ConverterParameter=1}" />
                                                <Button Background="Transparent" Margin="-100,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="400">
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,4,0,0"/>
                                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding MiddleName}" Margin="40,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                                                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding FirstName}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="40,-22,0,0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" Foreground="Gray"/>
                                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Text="," FontSize="20" Margin="0,-22,-3,0" Foreground="Gray"/>
                                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding LastName}" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,-22,0,0" FontSize="20" Foreground="Gray"/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <Button.Flyout>
                                                        <MenuFlyout Placement="Right">
                                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"/>
                                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit" x:Name="editsenderclick" Click="editsenderclick_Click"/>
                                                        </MenuFlyout>
                                                    </Button.Flyout>
                                                </Button>
                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle>
                            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                        </ListBox>
```

and c# :

`listSearchResults.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0]).ToList();
 listSearchResults.Sort((x,y)=> string.Compare(x.FirstName,y.FirstName));
 cvs.Source = listSearchResults;`

And i am getting this
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwZGY.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, I can suggest you group collection as code bellow:

```
cvs.Source = peopleCollection.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0]).ToList();
```

After that you retrieve object `List<IGrouping<char, Person>>` type.

Your mistake in defining `ListBox.GroupStyle`. You have to define only header presentation in this section and define `ItemTemplate` for your collection inside section. So you need separate code like this:

```
    <ListBox Background="#282828" x:Name="sendersearchresults" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="#FFCF06"
                                       FontSize="40"
                                       FontWeight="Normal" 
                                       Text="{Binding Key}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Background="Transparent" Margin="-100,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="400">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,4,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding MiddleName}" Margin="40,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding FirstName}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="40,-22,0,0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" Foreground="Gray"/>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Text="," FontSize="20" Margin="0,-22,-3,0" Foreground="Gray"/>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding LastName}" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,-22,0,0" FontSize="20" Foreground="Gray"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout Placement="Right">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit" x:Name="editsenderclick" Click="editsenderclick_Click"/>
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Look at final result (without Icon and MiddleName)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A]

Comment: Works like a charm.Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: Any idea why my images are not aligning?